# How to set default value of entity/view object's attribute via SQL in Oracle adf?

Tags: sql, oracle-adf, default-value

I want to set default value of ID attribute in view object via a sql query , i.e :

```
SELECT (MAX(DEPTID) + 1) 
FROM DEPARTMENT;
```

so that I can use it as an auto-increment feature in oracle-adf. I have used sequences for it too via java but it doesn't fulfill my requirement. I also tried the SQL method myself, but when I deploy the form the page is returned blank and when I run app-module it doesn't work as well.

[image: Image to show the SQL method I am implementing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this exact setup on JDeveloper 12.2.1.3 (current production) and it works fine. The BC Tester and Rendered page both show the incremented max dept id.

However, the "Transient Type" for me was set to "Number" if I set the Attribute type to BigDecimal and BigInt if I selected BigInteger. I notice in your screen shot it shows the type as "$none$" - perhaps this is the issue?

Also, if you are incrementing by a whole number, why choose BigDecimal for the Type? Shouldn't it be Integer or Big Integer?

Also, in case you don't know - it's a recommended practice to put the EOs, VOs, Links, Assocs, etc. into separate packages to make it easier to read, etc. Go to Tools > Preferences > ADF Business Components > packages.

Comment: Whenever I try to add SQL Query in the input field in overview window it sets the type of attribute to itself automatically.

Comment: you don't mention version of JDev/ADF - You're new here so *always* mention version and OS and other things to help us help you. It worked for me so not sure what to tell you. You might try doing a fresh install and test that - or log this question at the ADF community forum, here: https://community.oracle.com/community/groundbreakers/java/java_development_tools/application_development_in_java/jdeveloper_and_adf